# Xamarin Uploading sqllite file to Azure Blob storage, sqlite .db3 file is empty on Blob storage

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to upload the local database of the app build in Xamarin forms iOS. There is data in the local database and the app can see all the table and data just fine.

I want to investigate the database, so I upload it to an Azure Blob storage.

The code look like this:
public class BlobStorageService
    {
        readonly static CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Constants.blogStorageConnectionString);
        readonly static CloudBlobClient blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

```
    public static async Task UploadFileToBlobStorage(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            return;

        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("sqllitefiles");
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        BlobContainerPermissions permissions = await container.GetPermissionsAsync();
        permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;  //TODO: disable this later.
        await container.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(filePath);
    }
}
```

And the filePath is :
`public static readonly string DatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CaseNotesSQLite.db3");`

Database file is uploaded successfully, however, the file is only 4KB and when I open the database file using SQLLite Browser, there is no data and no table structure at all.

Anyone know why ?

Comment: are you closing any open SQLite connections before uploading the file?

Comment: Good point, let me double check